# IOS Xcode 5.1 Search Path in separate line

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5.1

In Xcode 5 and before all is fine, when I upgraded to Xcode 5.1, it got problem with Framework Search Path.

For example, this is the right one in Xcode 5
[image]

But this is what happened in Xcode 5.1
[image]

If I manual changed it to the first one, it will get an error says framework not found.

Comment: Delete all paths except $(inherited) and add this: **$(SRCROOT)** 
If your frameworks are in subfolders, add this : 
$(SRCROOT)/Subfolder/subfolder

Comment: @Thought-Beast thanks, but my framework is outside the project folder in Dropbox.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the framework via [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/)